# Keystone-next custom mutation

Tags: reactjs, next.js, keystonejs

can anyone suggest why my mutation isn't working. My app is keystone-next back end, apollo-boost and next.js. I have the fields in state and set them as variables but they don't get sent to the backend. I'm sure this worked before.

Backend custom mutation in keystone

```
async function locate(
  root: any, 
  { userId }: { userId: string }, 
  context: KeystoneContext
  ): Promise<LocationCreateInput> {
  // 1. Query the current user see if they are signed in
  const sesh = context.session as Session;
  if (!sesh.itemId) {
    throw new Error('You must be logged in to do this!');
  }
  // 2. Create the location object
  return await context.lists.Location.createOne({
    data: {
      user: { connect: { id: sesh.itemId }},
    }
  })
}
  export default locate;
```

and frontend in next.js

```
const LOCATE_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation LOCATE_MUTATION(
        $address: String
        $lat: String
        $lng: String
        ) {
        locate(data:{ address: $address, lat: $lat, lng: $lng }) {
            id
            address
            lat
            lng
            user {
                id
                name
            }
        }
        }
`;
const [locate, { error }] = 
    useMutation(LOCATE_MUTATION,{
      variables: {address: location, lat: slat, lng: slng}
    })
<button onClick={locate}>Set my Location</button>
```

and finally, my mutation as shown in apollo dev tools

```
Variables
address "Cambridge CB1, UK"
lat "52.1964114"
lng "0.1746102"
▾Mutation string
mutation LOCATE_MUTATION($address: String, $lat: String, $lng: String) {
  locate(data: {address: $address, lat: $lat, lng: $lng}) {
    id
    address
    lat
    lng
    user {
      id
      name
      __typename
    }
    __typename
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For troubleshooting purposes it's helpful to test mutations on their own, for instance via a GraphQL playground. This allows to narrow down the problem (is the problem coming from the mutation or the frontend?).

There is a disconnect between your mutation and the frontend: your mutation takes in a `userId` argument (which also is never used), but in the frontend you pass three variables: `address`, `lat`, and `lng`.

If the intent of your mutation is to create a `Location` entry (as opposed to simply associating an existing `Location` with a `User`), you need to add the three variables to the `data` object:

```
data: {
  address: address,
  lat: lat,
  lng: lng,
  user: { connect: { id: sesh.itemId }},
}
```

If you don't use the `userId` in your mutation you can remove it altogether.